# A regular expression for extracting a string followed by a particular string containing any no of characters and numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am stuck at a regular expression in which  have to extract a day and night data limit in python. What I need to extract is only the amount of data at night and day and my data looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/jhYTDXqA)

Since data is very big I want two regular expressions:

1. for retrieving night data available
2. for retrieving day data available

What I make for the "day data" is `([0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?\s?GB|[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?\s?MB).*\+` by which i will capture the string before + and then will capture the amount of data in python. This is correct for most of the data but not for all.I want max to be captured.

I want Two RE's that capture data preceded by 'day' and 'night'(there may be char and no in between also).For example:
4gb day + 3gb night data

output:

```
Day data limit    Night Data Limit
4GB                  3GB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patterns vary but from what I've managed to spot (without analysing all 6K+ lines) is that `day` or `night` usually come zero to two words after the respective amount. You may use positive lookahead to match a pattern only if it is followed by some other pattern.

So for the day data you may end up with

```
(?i)\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s?[MG]B(?=\s+(?:\S+\s+){0,2}day\b)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jdCtld/2

And for the night data it is pretty much the same:

```
(?i)\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s?[MG]B(?=\s+(?:\S+\s+){0,2}night\b)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/t2WSjz/3

Comment: one question what is {0,2} before night is doing?

Comment: ok i got it but the night one is not giving the answer. Coz somewhere it is away from + without space i tried adding \+ in non capturing group.It works but now it wont pick some of night data rows.Where i am wrong?

Comment: 6 GB + 4GB Night 3G/2G Data
Not matching to it for night one because of space?

Comment: Plz help me as i am still stuck and new to RE

Comment: @SimranGulati: Let's continue this discussion in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146875/q44569011-a44570545)

Comment: Well i do not have reputation of 20 to talk n chat coz I am new to stack overflow.But the issue is still there Now the data of type "1 GB 3G/2G Night Data + Unlimited Local On Net calls (00:00 hours - 06:00 hours) for Reliance GSM Customers (T&C: For Reliance 4G Customers : Unltd Local & STD R-R Calls+ Free 1GB 4G Data + All R -Others calls @1p/sec + Free Incoming Roaming for 28 days) " cant be captured

Comment: Changed the options from {0,3} before night still not working

Comment: Oh, I see. May I rely on the assumption that there would be no + between allowed night traffic amount and the Night word? If so, you may just replace generic "not space" (`\S`) with more restrictive "not space and not plus sign" (`[^\s+]`): [`(?i)\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s?[MG]B(?=\s+(?:[^\s+]\s+){0,2}night\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/OFnUR9/1)

Comment: Yes i have seen this comment there on chat. That's the RE for which the above "1 GB 3G/2G Night Data + Unlimited Local On Net calls (00:00 hours - 06:00 hours) for Reliance GSM Customers (T&C: For Reliance 4G Customers : Unltd Local & STD R-R Calls+ Free 1GB 4G Data + All R -Others calls @1p/sec + Free Incoming Roaming for 28 days)" s not captured